# Rails console error when testing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm following a guide from 2011 on how to create a simple rails application. In this case a URL shortener.

http://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-first-rails-application-models/

I am at the section for testing out models. Where I am required to open the Rails console and enter `puts Rails.env`to inspect the development environment.

Migration:

```
class CreateUrls < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
create_table :urls do |t|
  t.string :url, :null => false
  t.timestamps
end
end

def self.down
drop_table :urls
end
end
```

URL Model:

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :url, :presence > true
end
```

When I enter the command `u = Url.new`I am getting a wall of errors. I suspect that these may have something to do with versions of Ruby and Rails?

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
irb(main):001:0> u = Url.new
ArgumentError: comparison of Symbol with true failed
    from /Users/tomcox/development/projects/toolong/app/models/url.rb:2:in `>'
    from /Users/tomcox/development/projects/toolong/app/models/url.rb:2:in `<class:Url>'
    from /Users/tomcox/development/projects/toolong/app/models/url.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/tomcox/development/projects/toolong/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tomcox/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code for your Url model. There's no way we can help if we can't see the code where the failure is occuring.

Comment: Added the migration and Url model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had a typo:

```
validates :url, :presence > true
```

Should be:

```
validates :url, :presence => true
```